# cant remove Paths from echo $PATH

Tags: windows, cmd, path

i'm using CMD on windows 10.

I'm trying to clean Paths from "echo $PATH" but it doesn't work. I did try to just change it like:

```
   set PATH=C:\python\Scripts
```

and then when I do "echo $PATH" again it's working:

```
    C:\python\Scripts
```

But after I restarting VSC it switching back to old 26-th different paths again. I don't need it.

How I can PERMANENTLY remove it from the system?

I did try to reinstall VSC

I did try to clean cache EVERYWHERE, its not working.

No matter what i'm doing every time when i run "echo $PATH" its showing those 26 paths.

Please help

Comment: We cannot help you to fix something you've been unable to accurately describe. I can categorically tell you that if you used the command `set PATH=C:\python\Scripts` "using CMD on windows 10", the result of "`echo $PATH`", will never be `C:\python\Scripts`. Your question therefore requires editing to make it clear, correct and answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this occurs because `PATH` is a windows environment variable and it can be changed permanently in windows settings rather than VSC.

[windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#windows10)

Comment: Yes, i did found them there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to set `PATH` using cmd, it sets it temporarily.

To change it permanently,

Go to My Computer ---> Right Click on it ---> Advanced System Settings ---> Advanced Tab ---> Click on Environment Variables,

then you can add or delete paths that you don't need from there.

Comment: To change it permanently, use the `SETX` command. Use `SETX /?` for more information.